# How to display similar data from sqlite in listView?

Tags: database, sqlite

Say, I have a database with personName, age, country. I successfully inserted number of entries. Now I want to fetch all personName and age from same country. For example I want to display all people with age from U.S. in a listView. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this query and get the result.

```
SELECT personName, age FROM table WHERE country = 'U.S.'
```